# Sort a vector using a boolean predicate function in O(N) time

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

As an example, suppose I want to sort the vector {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, placing even numbers on the left and odd numbers on the right. I can devise an algorithm that does this in O(N) time (shown below). My question is, *is there an existing STL algorithm for something like this?*

## My (not very generic or pretty) solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/**
 Sort a vector of integers according to a boolean predicate function

 Reorders the elements of x such that elements satisfying some condition
 (i.e. f(x) = true) are arranged to the left and elements not satisfying the
 condition (f(x) = false) are arranged to the right
 (Note that this sort method is unstable)

 @param x vector of integers
 */
void sort_binary(std::vector<int>& x, bool (*func)(int)){
    // Strategy:
    // Simultaneously iterate over x from the left and right ends towards
    // the middle. When one finds {..., false, ..., ..., true, ....},
    // swap those elements

    std::vector<int>::iterator it1 = x.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator it2 = x.end();
    int temp;

    while(it1 != it2){
        while(func(*it1) && it1 < it2){
            ++it1;
        }
        while(!func(*it2) && it1 < it2){
            --it2;
        }
        if(it1 != it2){
            // Swap elements
            temp = *it1;
            *it1 = *it2;
            *it2 = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Sort a vector of ints so that even numbers are on the
    // left and odd numbers are on the right
    std::vector<int> foo {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    sort_binary(foo, [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; } );
    for(auto &x : foo) std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Comment: `std::partition`?

Comment: Technically that's not a *sort*.

Comment: @MarkRansom technically you cannot sort in O(N)

Comment: @Slava That's true for comparison-based sorts, but less general sorts can sort in O(n). For example, [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) sorts in O(n).

Comment: @Justin radix sort is secretly O(nlog(n)), it's just that the log(n) term is hidden in the size of the keys being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)

> Reorders the elements in the range [first, last) in such a way that all elements for which the predicate p returns true precede the elements for which predicate p returns false. Relative order of the elements is not preserved.

complexity:

> Exactly N applications of the predicate. At most N/2 swaps if ForwardIt meets the requirements of LegacyBidirectionalIterator, and at most N swaps otherwise.

```
std::partition( foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; } );
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/KfN2IP)

PS you can use [`std::stable_partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) if you want to preserve order of the elements

Comment: @Ben Going through [cppreference's list of algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is a good place to start. There are a lot, though, so it's helpful to become familiar with them over time.